# Towers of Hanoi recursive/iterative hybrid

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion, iteration

I have to make a iterative solution to the Towers of Hanoi problem. I am trying to convert a tail recursive call to an iterative one. I am following an algorithm I found in my textbook to transform it. I followed this algorithm and even though my code is similar to the recursive variant my output doesn't match the designated form. Now from what the book tells me, having a recursive call with an iterative is strange, but valid.

```
public class DemoIterative
{
    public static void TowersOfHanoi(int numberOfDisks, 
    String startPole, String tempPole, String endPole)
    {
        while (numberOfDisks > 0)
        {
            /** MUST GO 1, 3, 2, 1 */
            TowersOfHanoi(numberOfDisks - 1, startPole, endPole, tempPole);
            System.out.println(startPole + " -> " + endPole);
            numberOfDisks = numberOfDisks - 1;
            startPole = tempPole;
            tempPole = startPole;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        DemoIterative demoIterative = new DemoIterative();
        System.out.println("Enter amount of discs: ");
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        int discs = scanner.nextInt();
        demoIterative.TowersOfHanoi(discs, "A", "B", "C");
    } // end of main
} // end DemoIterative
```

### Now the output I am getting from this is:

A to C,
A to B,
C to B,
A to C,
B to B,
B to C,
B to C

### I should be getting this (tested from recursive original):

A to C,
A to B,
C to B,
A to C,
B to A,
B to C,
A to C

### This is the algorithm I am using:

While numberOfDisks is greater than 0, move disk from startPole to endPole, numberOfDisks--, exchange the contents of tempPole and startPole.

Now is this possible? If so, is there a problem with my algorithm or am I printing it wrong?

Comment: To make an iterative algo out of a recursive one you need a stack (push, pop).

Comment: Why are you creating an object to invoke a static method? You don't need to do that, just call it from the class

Answer (score 0):

You have a problem with your algorithm.  Most important for your own understanding of this, slap a **print** statement at the top of your routine and print out the arguments.  Also insert one at the bottom of the loop to help track that execution.

To summarize, I don't think you understand the call tree you've created, and I think you should trace it to see.  There are applications that will use such a tree, but I don't think that this what you want for this assignment.

There area couple of structural problems.  For one, when you get to the bottom of the loop, you set **startPole = tempPole**, and follow that with a useless assignment back -- this wipes out the old **startPole** value; it does not exchange them.

Next, your loop + recursion structure is strange.  First, you've used a *while* loop where the semantics clearly indicate a *for* -- you know how many times you'll iterate when you enter the loop.  When you first call this with, say, 5 disks, the numberOfDisks (I'll call it N) = 5 iteration will loop 5 times.  Each iteration recurs with N = 4, 3, 2, 1, respectively.

Now, the N=4 instance will do likewise: recurring with N=3, 2, 1.  This gives you *two* instances at N=3.  Continuing, you'll get *three* instances at N=2, and *four* at N=1, for a total of **11** calls to your function.  Since only four of these involve moving a one-disk stack (for a tower of 5 disks, you need several more), I think you've incorrectly implemented whatever you had in mind.